# How to automatically login a new user after registration with a custom user provider in Silex?

Tags: php, silex

Context : I created a custom user provider for my Silex Application and I can now register and log my own user perfectly. However, I need now to automatically log in my user after registration and this doesn't work.

Here is my security section :

```
'secured' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/',
        'anonymous' => false,
        'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/login_check'),
        'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/logout', 'invalidate_session' => true),
        'users' => $app->share(function () use ($app) {
            return new Partner\DAO\PartnerDAO($app['db']);
        })
    )
```

Here is my userProviderInterface :

```
public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    if (!$user instanceof Partner) {
        throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user)));
    }

    return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
}


public function supportsClass($class)
{
    return 'Partner\Entity\Partner' === $class;
}
```

With Xdebug, I can see that here :

```
  foreach ($this->userProviders as $provider) {
        try {
            $refreshedUser = $provider->refreshUser($user);
            $token->setUser($refreshedUser);

            if (null !== $this->logger) {
                $this->logger->debug('User was reloaded from a user provider.', array('username' => $refreshedUser->getUsername(), 'provider' => get_class($provider)));
            }

            return $token;
```

`$this->userProviders` only contains one provider : `'Users' => null`

Note that :

Login, register and logout work perfectly. This error is only triggered when I want to automatically login my user after registration. Here is the code :

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($partner, null, 'secured', $partner->getRoles());
// Note that $partner->getRoles()  is array('ROLE_USER')
$app['security.token_storage']->setToken($token);
return $app->redirect($app["url_generator"]->generate("partner_home"));
```

After registration, I automatically create the token and redirect the user in the secured area but Silex redirect it on the login page and if I click somewhere i get :

> There is no user provider for user "Partner\Entity\Partner".

I don't know where to search anymore and I could really need some help.

Comment: Your update looks like an answer. Would you consider moving that to an answer proper, to make this clear? Others can still add answers if they wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Founded a solution, more like a workaround, but it make the job :

Instead of using the security/token method, I now log the user by generating a request to the login_check controller in order to generate all necessary login event.

In my controller :

```
$subRequest = Request::create(
$app['url_generator']->generate('login_check'),
    'POST',
    array(
        '_username' => $partner->getEmail(),
        '_password' => $rawPassword,
        $request->cookies->all(),
        array(),
        $request->server->all()
    )
);
$app->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST, false);
```

Wich require "'require_previous_session' => false" in your firewall configuration :

```
'secured' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/',
        'anonymous' => false,
        'form' => array(
            'login_path' => '/login',
            'check_path' => '/login_check',
            'require_previous_session' => false
        ),
        'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/logout', 'invalidate_session' => true),
        'users' => $app->share(function () use ($app) {
            return new Partner\DAO\PartnerDAO($app['db']);
        })
    )
```

I'm not sure it's a good or a bad solution, but it's working.

Comment: I had the same problem, solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044369/automatic-login-after-registration-in-silex