# Automatic login after registration in Silex

Tags: php, authentication, silex

I want to automatically login user after registering. First I tried this way 
https://gist.github.com/simonjodet/3927516. Bu tit did not work. I found out someone else had the same problem and found a workaround in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32744298/how-to-automatically-login-a-new-user-after-registration-with-a-custom-user-prov), but it does not work for me.

This is my code, the login process works correctly. But not login automatically when registering.

My security configuration:

```
    $app['security.firewalls'] = array(
    'main' => array(
        'pattern' => '^(/user|/logout|/login_check)',   
        'form' => array(
            'login_path' => '/login/',
            'check_path' => '/login_check/',
            'require_previous_session' => false,
            'username_parameter'=> 'form[email]',
            'password_parameter' => 'form[password]'

        ),
        'remember_me' => array(
            'key' => 'adfafasfasdfdasfasdfa',   //whatever random string
            'remember_me_parameter' => 'form[remember]'
        ),
        'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/logout/', 'invalidate_session' => true),
        'users' =>  function(Silex\Application $app){
            return $app['user_manager'];
        }
    )
);
```

My UserController.php code on signing up:

```
if ($signupForm->isValid()) {
       $plainPassword = $data['password'];
      //preparing data to be inserted
      $password = self::encodePassword($data['email'], $plainPassword, $app['security.encoder.digest']);
      //inserting the user
      $userManager->insertUser($data, $password, $app['slugger']);
      //generate a request to login_check       
      $subRequest = \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::create(
        '/login_check/',
        'POST',
        array(
            'form[email]' => $data['email'],
            'form[password]' => $plainPassword,
             $app['request']->cookies->all(),
             array(),
             $app['request']->server->all()
        ));
        $app->handle($subRequest, \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST, false);
```

I am using the user email as what it should be user provider 'username'. 
It does not login, and this is Monolog's output. Username is 'NONE_PROVIDED' while it should be the user's email.

```
    [2016-03-16 19:29:41] myapp.INFO: Matched route "POST_login_". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"user.controller:login","_route":"POST_login_"},"request_uri":"http://local.mysite.com/login/"} []
[2016-03-16 19:29:41] myapp.INFO: > POST /login/ [] []
[2016-03-16 19:29:41] myapp.INFO: Matched route "POST_login_check_". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"loginCheck","_route":"POST_login_check_"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/login_check/"} []
[2016-03-16 19:29:41] myapp.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): Bad credentials. at /home/myuser/www/local.mysite.com/vendor/symfony/security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php:73, Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\UsernameNotFoundException(code: 0): Username \"NONE_PROVIDED\" does not exist. at /home/myuser/www/local.mysite.com/app/Model/Manager/UserManager.php:58)"} []
[2016-03-16 19:29:41] myapp.DEBUG: Authentication failure, redirect triggered. {"failure_path":"/login/"} []
[2016-03-16 19:29:41] myapp.INFO: < 302 http://localhost/login/ [] []
[2016-03-16 19:29:41] myapp.INFO: < 200 [] []
```

EDIT:

While asking, I found out that maybe the problem is that when I make the automatic request I am sending it from 'localhost' instead of 'local.mysite.com', how to fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would opt for the gist instead of the redirect, this seems hackish to me.

For new Symfony Security component you need to adapt the code a little bit. From [SO this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637172/manual-authenticate-user):

```
<?php
// on your user registration controller...

// create and store an authenticated token
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
    $user, 
    $user->getPassword(), 
    'main',                 //key of the firewall you are trying to authenticate 
    $user->getRoles()
);
$app['security.token_storage']->setToken($token);

// _security_main is, again, the key of the firewall
$app['session']->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
$app['session']->save(); // this will be done automatically but it does not hurt to do it explicitly

return $app->redirect('/where-ever-you-want');
```

I haven't tested this code!

**UPDATE** 
For reference, Symfony documentation has a good example of this: [How to Simulate Authentication with a Token in a Functional Test](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html)